# How can I solve NoMethodError from from ROR?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Can anybody please help me to resolve the below error.

## Error:

```
NoMethodError in Homes#managebooks

Showing C:/Site/library_management1/app/views/homes/managebooks.html.erb where line #48 raised:

undefined method `book_name' for #<Array:0x229d340>
```

Actually I want fetch all data to the existing table to display after submitting.When i clicked on submit button all the data saved into DB but after that it is throwing the above error.Please help to resolve those error very soon.

My codes are as follows.

## views/homes/managebooks.html.erb

```
<% if admin_signed_in? %>
<div class="bar">
  Logged in as <strong><%= current_admin.email %></strong>.
  <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_admin_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %> |
  <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_admin_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
</div>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_admin_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %> |
  <%= link_to "Login", new_admin_session_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
<% end %>
<div class="big-container">
    <% if flash[:color]== "valid" %>
        <div class="valid_notice">
            <p><%= flash[:notice]%></p>
        </div>
    <% elsif flash[:color]== "invalid"%>
        <div class="invalid_notice">
            <p><%=flash[:notice]%></p>
        </div>
    <%else%>
        <div class="notice">
            <p><%=flash[:notice]%></p>
        </div>
    <%end%>
<div class="admin-image">
 <div class="bpaddingdiv1"><img src="/assets/admin.png" border="0" name="admin" /></div>
</div>
<div class="borderlightgreen"></div>
<div class="admin-name">
<div class="tpaddingdiv2 textaligncenterdiv"><img src="/assets/adminpanel.png" border="0" name="admin" /></div>
</div>
<div class="leftside">
<div id="leftsidebtn">
 <ul>
<li><a href="/homes/managebooks">Manage Books</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Manage Pages</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Manage Header Banner</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Brand</a></li>
 </ul>  
</div>
</div>
<div class="middlebox">
<center>
    <%= form_for :books,:url => {:action => "savebooks"} do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
         <p>
            <label for="name">Book name</label>
            <%= f.text_field :book_name,placeholder:"enter book name" %>
         </p>

         <p>
            <label for="tel">Book title</label>
            <%= f.text_field :book_title,placeholder:"enter book title" %>
         </p>

         <p>
            <label for="email">Author Name</label>
           <%= f.text_field :author_name,placeholder:"enter book author name" %>
         </p>

         <p>
            <label for="password">publisher Name</label>
            <%= f.text_field :publisher_name,placeholder:"enter book publisher name" %>
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="password"> Edition</label>
           <%= f.text_field :edition,placeholder:"enter book edition" %>
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="password">Pages</label>
           <%= f.text_field :pages,placeholder:"enter book pages" %>
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="password"> Date of pursase</label>
            <%= f.date_select :date_of_purchase %>
         </p>

         <p>
            <%= f.submit "SUBMIT" %>
         </p>
    </fieldset>
 <% end %>
</center>
<% if params[:id] %>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Book name</th>
<th>Book title</th>
<th>Author Name</th>
<th>publisher Name </th>
<th>Edition</th>
<th>Pages</th>
<th>Date of pursase</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><%= @books.book_name %></td>
    <td><%= @books.book_title %></td>
    <td><%= @books.author_name %></td>
    <td><%= @books.publisher_name %></td>
    <td><%= @books.edition %></td>
    <td><%= @books.pages %></td>
    <td><%= @books.date_of_purchase  %></td>
    <td><%= image_tag("/assets/1.png") %></td>
    <td><%= link_to(
      image_tag(
        "/assets/logout.png", 
        :alt => "image", :width => 40, :height => 40, :title => "Delete item"
      ),
      homes_remove_path(:id => @books.id),
      :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure to remove this?") %>
  </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<% end  %>
</div>
</div>
```

## controller/homes_controller.rb

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
     before_filter :authenticate_admin!,only: [:admin]
    def index

    end
    def admin

    end
    def managebooks
        @books=Book.new
        if params[:id]
            @books=Book.all
        end
    end
    def savebooks
        @books=Book.new(params[:books])
        if @books.save
            flash[:notice]="Data has submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'managebooks',:id => @books.id
        else
            flash[:notice]="Data couldnot submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'managebooks'
        end
    end
    def remove
        @books=Book.find(params[:id])
        @books.destroy
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this section of your erb code:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= @books.book_name %></td>
  <td><%= @books.book_title %></td>
  <td><%= @books.author_name %></td>
  <td><%= @books.publisher_name %></td>
  <td><%= @books.edition %></td>
  <td><%= @books.pages %></td>
  <td><%= @books.date_of_purchase  %></td>
  <td><%= image_tag("/assets/1.png") %></td>
  <td><%= link_to(
    image_tag(
      "/assets/logout.png", 
      :alt => "image", :width => 40, :height => 40, :title => "Delete item"
    ),
    homes_remove_path(:id => @books.id),
    :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure to remove this?") %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

to this:

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= book.book_name %></td>
    <td><%= book.book_title %></td>
    <td><%= book.author_name %></td>
    <td><%= book.publisher_name %></td>
    <td><%= book.edition %></td>
    <td><%= book.pages %></td>
    <td><%= book.date_of_purchase  %></td>
    <td><%= image_tag("/assets/1.png") %></td>
    <td><%= link_to(
      image_tag(
        "/assets/logout.png", 
        :alt => "image", :width => 40, :height => 40, :title => "Delete item"
      ),
      homes_remove_path(:id => book.id),
      :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure to remove this?") %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

If you look at your method `managebooks` in `homes` controller then it creates an array of `Book` objects if `:id` is present in `params`.

NOTE: The above change will again fail since we're using `each` method on `@books`, which is not defined for a new `Book` object if there's no `:id` in `params`.